# Batch file to eject USB External Drive that is "in use"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that copies files from and to an external hard drive. I wanted to add a section at the end of the script that would automatically eject the hard drive so it could be safely removed. I did some research and found that `Remove Drive` is my best option. I have it set up to use and working. I can write a bat file

```
@echo off
RemoveDrive :E -L
```

and it works perfectly!

However, I've hit a snag. When I add this exact line (well without the `@echo off`) to the end of my bat file, it fails to eject. My guess is that its the same problem as when you've got files open from a usb drive and try to eject it. It won't work because the system is using it. I tested this by creating a seperate bat file that ran just the `RemoveDrive` named it "RemoveDrive.bat". I then added to the end of my batch file:

```
pause
call "RemoveDrive.bat"
```

When the script hit the `pause` command. I tried to run the batch file by simply clicking the icon. The eject attempt failed. I pressed any key to continue and the called bat file failed and the script (and cmd window) closed. I then double clicked the icon for "RemoveDrive.bat" and it worked.

So after that long explanation, I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for how to work around this. I was thinking if there was a way I could use the `call` function with some sort of delay and could close the cmd window. If I could get the cmd window to close and then have the bat file run automatically, I'm betting that would work.

Comment: If you are trying execute removedrive.exe without using the extension and your batch file is named removedrive.bat, it will try to execute removedrive.bat instead of removedrive.exe.

Comment: As above, just rename your `.bat` file **RemDrive.bat**

Comment: @Compo I tried it, and it didn't work. It shouldn't be an issue though. The command for RemoveDrive.exe is using its full path to the System32 folder. The bat file was using the `CALL` command with the .bat extension.

Comment: I have used the utility myself, other than the EULA you get on first run, the program has always done what was asked of it, although I do recall a couple of occasions where I wasn't sure if I'd had to invoke the command more than once. You do know that you don't flush and eject, eject flushes first `sync64 -e H:`

Comment: @Compo maybe I am just missing something. What is the exact commands to use with sync64 if I wanted to eject an external hard drive "E:"? Because yes it flushes the drive, but nothing else happens.

Comment: The command was in my last comment, 32-bit `sync.exe -e E:` 64-bit `sync64.exe -e E:`

Comment: @Compo, that's exactly what I put. It flushes the drive, but it does not eject the drive.

Comment: Where is your batch file located?

Comment: @DavidPostill the desktop

Comment: What Windows version do (did?) you have? I've tried to use `RemoveDrive :E` on Win 10 (x64 Pro) and it says that RemoveDrive is not a name of a command or executable..

Comment: Squashman, that sounds very unusual, that BAT would take precedence over EXE. Am I mistaken, or are the only times that that would happen be either 1. environment variable PATHEXT has been specifically reordered away from the classic (and default, IINM for every windows version up thru Win 10) priority sequence COM then EXE then BAT; or 2., the BAT is in the current directory, while the EXE is in a PATHed directory which is not the current directory. (Current dir trumps path, regardless of extension priority.)